# ¿Cómo actualizar Lcobucci\JWT\ de la versión 3.2.5 a la versión 5.x?

Tags: php, jwt

Actualmente tengo un proyecto en **Laravel 5.5** que utiliza la librería **Lcobucci\JWT**, específicamente la versión **3.2.5**.

Quiero actualizar a **Laravel 10.2.x** que utiliza la librería **Lcobucci\JWT**, específicamente la versión **5.x**.

Intenté leer estos pasos: [Documentación de Lcobucci - Guía paso a paso](https://lcobucci-jwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/upgrading/)

Mi **app/Auth/Jwt.php**:

**Antes:**

```
function __construct($signatureKey) {
    $this->signatureKey = $signatureKey;
    $this->signer = new Sha256();
}
```

**Ahora:**

```
public function __construct(Configuration $config)
{
    $this->config = $config;
}
```

**Antes:**

```
public function generateToken(array $payload) {
    $tb= new Builder();
    $tb->setIssuer('Issuer');
    $tb->setIssuedAt(time());
    $tb->setExpiration(time() + 3600);

    foreach ($payload as $key => $value) {
        $tb->set($key, $value);
    }
    
    $tb->sign($this->signer, $this->signatureKey);

    return $tb->getToken();
}
```

**Ahora:**

```
public function generateToken(): Token
{
    return $this->config->builder()
        ->identifiedBy(bin2hex(random_bytes(16)))
        ->getToken($this->config->signer(), $this->config->signingKey());
}
```

**Antes:**

```
public function verifyToken($token) {
    try {
        $token = (new Parser())->parse((string) $token);
        return $token->verify($this->signer, $this->signatureKey);
    } catch (RuntimeException $e) {
        return false;   
    } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        return false;   
    }
}
```

**Ahora:**

```
public function verifyToken(string $jwt)
{
    $token = $this->config->parser()->parse($jwt);

    if(! $this->config->validator()->validate($token, ...$this->config->validationConstraints())) {
        return false;
    }

    return $token;
}
```

**Antes:**

```
public function isExpiredToken($token) {
    try {
        $token = (new Parser())->parse((string) $token);
        return $token->isExpired();
    } catch (RuntimeException $e) {
        return false;   
    } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        return false;   
    }
}
```

**Ahora:**

- Desconozco como migrar este método

**Antes:**

```
public function getIdFromToken($token) {
    $token = (new Parser())->parse((string) $token);
    return $token->getClaim('id');
}
```

**Ahora:**

- Desconozco como migrar este método

Intenté seguir la guía pero no funciona, el último error que tengo es:

```
Argument #1 ($config) must be of type Lcobucci\JWT\Configuration, string given, called in C:\p\my_project\app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php on line 17 {"exception":"[object] (TypeError(code: 0): App\\Auth\\Jwt::__construct(): Argument #1 ($config) must be of type Lcobucci\\JWT\\Configuration, string given, called in ....
```